# Override Material UI TextField label to fit responsive div

Tags: reactjs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN3ib.jpg

As you see in above, when I shrink my window, I want the labels to stay in that div. I am able to do it using width: fit-content but I don't know how to override .MuiFormLabel-root, any guess?

I am using makeStyles but it only overrides the textfield, not the label.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField name='population' label='Population:' type='number' className={classes.item}
               InputLabelProps={{
                  style: {
                     width: '-webkit-fill-available'
                  }
               }}
               error={errorPop} inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
               defaultValue={city.population} />
```

Got it, InputLabelProps then put in the style... I don't know why inputProps wouldn't work, I guess their different.